# How to mock the functionality of the test class itself using Moq in ASP.NET MVC unit test

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. In my project, I am doing unit testing. I use Moq for unit test. But I am having a problem with testing a method of a model class that has dependency on another of its functions.

This is the sample of model class that I want to test

```
public class ItemRepo:IItemRepo
{
    private DbContext context = new DbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return context.items;
    }

    public string GenerateItemCode()
    {
       Item item = this.GetItems.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
       //do something
       return itemCode;
    }
}
```

I want to test GenerateItemCode method

```
    [TestClass]
    public class ItemRepoTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GenerateItemCode_IncreaseDigit()
        {
            Item[] items = new Item[]{
                new Item{
                    ItemCode = "DN999934"
                }
            };
            ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo();
            //I want to mock GetItems method here
        }
    }
```

I commented what I want to mock in test code. How can I mock that method? How can I unit test that method mocking dependency function?

Comment: How is `items` introduced to the model. is it created internally or injected into the class.

Comment: The code inside of the GetItems method in this question is rather important, Please can you add it, as will show us how you are getting data from the database. For example if it is using EF DbContext then we could suggest that you inject in a mock DbContext to run Unit Tests against.

Comment: GetItems method is just return context.Items

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that your issue can be reproduced and a solution can be suggested. You are provided bits and pieces in comments. eg no where in your original question is there any mention of a context. Try updating your question with the relevant details.

Comment: Yes I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you are getting items from a context class, This is the class that you need to be Mocking.

There are many articles around that explain how to mock a DbContext, Top result on a google search [How to mock DbContext and DbSet with Moq for unit testing?](http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit)

```
[TestClass]
public class ItemRepoTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateItemCode_IncreaseDigit()
    {
       Item[] items = new Item[]{
               new Item{
                          ItemCode = "DN999934"
                       }
        };

       var mockContext = new Mock<YourContext>();
       // Code to inject items into mock context

       // You may have to implement the context injection into your ItemRepo 
       // class if you do not already have it

       ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo(mockContext.Object);

       var result = itemRepo.GenerateItemCode();

      // Code to check result is correct
   }
}
```

So basically, you create a mock DbContext in your unit test and pass in a fake list or such of item data. You then inject this mock into the class that you are testing, run the test, and if all is well and good with your code, the correct result will spit out at the other end

Comment: I deleted my previous comments. The problem is it mock IDbSet. But my context using DbSet. I cannot mock with DbSet. So I changed all IDbSet in my context class for entities. But when I change to IDbSet, there are functions that use removeRange with Items. So I cannot use removeRange to IDbSet. So any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

replace the  GetItems with a delegate:

```
 public class ItemRepo : IItemRepo
 {
     public Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Item>> Items = () => 
       {  // all your orignal code 
          return items;
       };  

      public string GenerateItemCode()
      {
         Item item = Items().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
         //do something
         return itemCode;
      }
 }
```

in the test code replace your delegate:

```
 public class ItemRepoTests
 {
     [TestMethod]
     public void GenerateItemCode_IncreaseDigit()
     {
        Item[] items = new Item[]{
            new Item{
                ItemCode = "DN999934"
            }
        };
        ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo();
        itemRepo.Items = () => items;
        //I want to mock GetItems method here

         itemRepo.GenerateItemCode()
     }
  }
```

pseudo code not testet, only to describe the idea

Comment: If I use delegate, I cannot access other properties of tested class inside from delegate function.